# Java Serializable Object fails

Tags: java, serialization, notserializableexception

I am having an issue with writing a Serializable object to a file.  I have been able to narrow the problem down, but have no idea what would cause this, so I'm just looking for advice anyone may have, because I can't really give an example, but I will give some shell code to paint the picture.

Basically I have an object storing information about the program that I save by writing the object to file.  It has a DefaultComboBoxModel which is part of what is causing my issue.  For example:

```
public class ProgramInfo implements Serializable {
     private DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
     // A bunch of other stuff

     public DefaultComboBoxModel getModel() {
         return model;
     }
     public void setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel m) {
         model = m;
     }
}
```

Then, I have a class which extends JPanel and looks like this:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {
    private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
    private ProgramInfo programInfo;
    // A bunch of other stuff

    public SomePanel(ProgramInfo info) {
        programInfo = info;
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(programInfo.getModel());
    }
}
```

The issue occurs after I add an element to DefaultComboBoxModel by calling model.addElement().  However, the issue does not occur if I only have one instance of SomePanel in my program, but if I create a second instance of SomePanel, it throws a java.io.NotSerializableException on the object SomeOtherClass when trying to write ProgramInfo to file.  If I comment out SomeOtherClass, then the next object in the SomePanel class throws the same error when trying to write ProgramInfo to file.

As a note, I am not an expert programmer, it is just a hobby and I am completely self taught.  Any advice/reading material on why this could happen would be great.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This exception occurs when the object or member(s) of the object is not serializable. Check if this is the case.

Comment: "I have been able to narrow the problem down ..." To what? "but have no idea what would cause this." Cause what? Exception? Stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Fields must also be serializable so you should check if `DefaultComboBoxModel` implements `Serializable`. I suspect it does not.

You should see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250) as a reference for Serialization of an object.